# Loopback 4 OpenAPI connector: Specify Authorization header value per request

Tags: loopbackjs, openapi

I have set up an OpenAPI connector in Loopback 4 as described [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/OpenAPI-connector.html#loopback-4-usage) and for unauthorized requests, it is working well; I managed to create the respective datasource, service and controller. My service is similar to the [GeocoderProvider example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/todo/src/services/geocoder.service.ts), but, let's say, with the following service interface.

```
export interface MyExternalService {
  search_stuff(params: {query?: string}): Promise<MyExternalServiceResponse>;
}

export interface MyExternalServiceResponse {
  text: string;
}
```

From my controller, I invoke it like this, where `this.myExternalService` is the injected service (kind of unrelated, but can Loopback also implicitly parse a JSON response from an external API datasource?):

```
  @get('/search')
  async searchStuff(@param.query.string('query') query: string): Promise<void> {
    return JSON.parse(
      (await this.myExternalService.search_stuff({query})).text,
    );
  }
```

Now, the external endpoint corresponding to `myExternalService.search_stuff` needs an `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header, where the token is sent to Loopback *by the client*, i.e. it's not a static API key or so. Assuming I added `@param.query.string('token') token: string` to the parameter list of my `searchStuff` controller method, how can I forward that token to the OpenAPI connector? This is the relevant part of the underlying OpenAPI YAML definition file:

```
paths:
  /search:
    get:
      security:
        - Authorization: []
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SearchResults'
      operationId: search-stuff
components:
  securitySchemes:
    Authorization:
      type: http
      scheme: Bearer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am now using the underlying `execute` function of the OpenAPI connector and manually intercept the request (the object that is passed to `requestInterceptor` is later passed directly to the http module by Swagger):

```js
    return JSON.parse(
      (
        await this.myExternalService.execute(
          'search_stuff',
          {query},
          {
            requestInterceptor: (req: {headers: {Authorization: string}}) => {
              req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
              return req;
            },
          },
        )
      ).text,
    );
```

I also added the following method to the `MyExternalService` interface, inspired by [the connector's actual `execute` function](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-openapi/blob/master/lib/openapi-connector.js#L184):

```
  execute(
    operationId: string,
    parameters: object,
    options: object,
  ): Promise<MyExternalServiceResponse>;
```

Some things I found:

- Loopback internally uses the [`swagger-client`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) module to do OpenAPI-based requests.
- Specifically the `securities` option of Swagger's execute function expects a [Security Definitions Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object). There are [some quirks](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1258#issue-303653293) with actually passing it to Swagger as well.
- Internally, Swagger builds the final HTTP request that is sent out [here in its source code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/src/execute/index.js#L90). There, the `securities` key is mentioned, yet is is never actually used for the request. This means that manually specifying it in the third parameter of `this.myExternalService.execute` will change nothing.

I'll not accept this answer yet and I'm looking forward to finding a more Loopback-like approach.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I'm surprised this use case does not seem to be easier in loopback. This is so far the only page and answer that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

I configured my service like this, to inject the basic authentication.

```
import {inject, lifeCycleObserver, LifeCycleObserver} from '@loopback/core';
import {juggler} from '@loopback/repository';
const SwaggerClient = require('swagger-client');

const config = {
  name: 'jira',
  connector: 'openapi',
  spec: 'swagger-v2.json',
  validate: false,
  httpClient: (request: any) => {
    request.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Buffer.from("test:test").toString('base64');
    return SwaggerClient.http(request);
  },
};

@lifeCycleObserver('datasource')
export class JiraDataSource extends juggler.DataSource
  implements LifeCycleObserver {
  static dataSourceName = 'jira';
  static readonly defaultConfig = config;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.config.jira', {optional: true})
    dsConfig: object = config,
  ) {
    super(dsConfig);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you deal with non static tokens (i.e. extracting them from a request before passing them to the connector service)?

Comment: Yes, the original post is asking for a non-static, non-hardcoded token:

_Now, the external endpoint corresponding to myExternalService.search_stuff needs an Authorization: Bearer <token> header, where the token is sent to Loopback by the client, i.e. it's not a static API key or so._